# Aurelia repeat.for limit

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm developing an app with Aurelia and let's say I have a loop there:

```
<div repeat.for="t of allTags">${t.name}</div>
```

There are many entries so naturally I would like to limit number of them shown. So basically I would like to have something like Angular's repeat limit:

```
<div ng-repeat="t in allTags | limitTo:5 ">{{t.name}}</div>
```

I have checked the docs here http://aurelia.io/docs.html but haven't found anything on the topic.

Is there a feature like that in Aurelia? If no, would I rather cut the list in controller of do it in the view with `$index`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Option 1: Use a value converter.

**take-value-converter.js**

```js
export class TakeValueConverter {
  toView(array, count) {
    return array.slice(0, count);
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```html
<require from="./take-value-converter"></require>

<div repeat.for="t of allTags | take:5">${t.name}</div>
```

Live example of this scenario and many others **[here](http://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-converters-sample/)**.

Other docs on value converters at aurelia.io

## Option 2: repeat over a number

```html
<div repeat.for="i of 5">${allTags[i].name}</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to start at an index different than 0?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start at a different value you can edit the `TakeValueConverter` 
at the `toView` method add a third parameter.

```
toView(array,start,count){
  return array.slice(start,count);
}
```

But then you have to track the last position somehow yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
<div if.bind="$index<5" repeat.for="t of allTags">${t.name}</div>
```

Using the Index and if to block rest of the records that are over criteria of index